# iterator operator++ overload compiling error

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, class-template

I have a linked list that contains a pointer to the first and last node and size which indicates how many nodes are there in the list.
I've implemented iterator for Queue that points to the address of the node, I've already succeeded implementing begin(),end() and ==,!=, and tested too,
but I'm unable to implement ++() and ++(int) operators for the iterators, i want the ++ operator to change the address of the node to the next one in the linked list, i get the following error when i try to compile: `no matching function for call to ‘Node<int>::getNext() const’`
and how can i make the iterator operator overload to work without typing `typename` at the start of the declaration

`Node` class:

```
template<class T>
class Node {
    public:
        Node(const T& t);
        ~Node()=default; // Destructor
        Node(const Node&) = default; // Copy Constructor set to default
        Node& operator=(const Node&) = default; // Assignment operator set to default
        T& getData();
        const T& getData() const;
        Node* getNext();
        void setNext(Node<T>* newNext);
    private:
        T m_data;
        Node* m_nextNode;
};

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& t) {
    this->m_data=t;
    this->m_nextNode=nullptr;
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getNext() {
    return this->m_nextNode;
}
```

`Queue` class:

```
template<class T>
class Queue {
    public:
        static const int DEFAULT_FIRST_INDEX=0;
        static const int SIZE_EMPTY=0;
        Queue();
        ~Queue(); // Destructor
        Queue(const Queue&) = default; // Copy Constructor set to default
        Queue& operator=(const Queue&) = default; // Assignment operator set to default
        void pushBack(const T& t);
        T& front();
        const T& front() const;
        void popFront();
        int size() const;
        class Iterator;
        Iterator begin() const;
        Iterator end() const;
        class EmptyQueue {};
    private:
        Node<T>* m_head;
        Node<T>* m_tail;
        int m_size;
};
```

`Queue<T>::Iterator` class:

```
template<class T>
class Queue<T>::Iterator {
    public:
        const T& operator*() const;
        Iterator& operator++();
        Iterator operator++(int);
        bool operator==(const Iterator& iterator) const;
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& iterator) const;
        Iterator(const Iterator&)=default;
        Iterator& operator=(const Iterator&)=default;
        class InvalidOperation {};
    private:
        const Node<T>* m_node;
        Iterator(const Node<T>* m_node);
        friend class Queue<T>;
};

template<class T>
Queue<T>::Iterator::Iterator(const Node<T>* m_node) {
    this->m_node=m_node;
}

template<class T>
typename Queue<T>::Iterator& Queue<T>::Iterator::operator++() {
    this->m_node=m_node->getNext();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Well, like it says, there's no such function `Node::getNext()` that works on a `const Node`. Why is `Node::getNext` non-`const` to begin with?

Comment: @NathanPierson
i tried adding `const Node* getNext() const;`
but now i get
`In function Queue<int>::Iterator::operator++()':
Queue.h:239: undefined reference to Node<int>::getNext() const'`

Comment: Did you change both the declaration and the definition?

Comment: @NathanPierson
i just added this definition without changing anything in declaration

Comment: Can you show the version of the code that tries to have `getNext() const`? It actually sounds like you just added a _declaration_ without including a definition, and you need a definition.

Comment: @NathanPierson
i changed the declartion to `Node* getNext() const;` , did the same to the definition and now it works, but still how do i make it work without `typename` at the start of the definition?

Comment: You can't. As the compiler sais you have to use `typename` *because 'Queue<T>' is a dependent scope*.

Comment: Why do you define the methods outside the class? It makes sense if you place the definitions into a separate translation unit but for template classes with the definition in the header it's just simpler to define all the methods directly in the class.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow
homework code conventions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make it work without `typename` at the start of the definition?

If you meant about the function `Queue<T>::Iterator::operator++()` definition, you can do it via [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) as follows:

```
template<class T>
auto Queue<T>::Iterator::operator++() -> Iterator&
//^^^                                    ^^^^^^^^^
{
    this->m_node = m_node->getNext();
    return *this;
}
```

That been said, (IMO) moving definitions outside the same transition unit for template classes or template functions is a bit verbose and tedious.